# Dummy return value for Generic Method

Tags: java, generics, return-type

I'm writing a few empty generic methods that I plan on coming back to finish later. However, I still want the program to compile. How do I return an empty generic method?

For example:

```
public AnyType getData()
{
   return ???
}
```

Do I have have to declare AnyType first and return the variable?

Comment: 1) `return null;` always works if you're not dealing with a primitive or better yet: 2) throw a "UnsupportedOperationException"" exception.

Comment: `public <T> T foo() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not yet completed");
  }`